# Animate MKMapView frame nicely

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, mkmapview

I'm trying to animate `MKMapView` frame using `UIView.animate(duration: 3) {...}`. But there is a problem, because when `frame` and `annotations` are nicely animated, map content itself just jumps into new position. I would like it to stretch nice and slow, just like other elements. Is there some way to do this?

This video shows that behavior:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zsx46m0k70fujl0/ScreenRecording_11-07-2017%2023%3A54.MP4?dl=0